# How to set Nodes from FXML JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have created a Layout with FXML which consists of a BorderPane with a sideMenu and an innerBorderPane for other stuff...

But since I'm barely starting with FXML in JavaFX I just need to know how to do the next thing...

**Custom.fxml** (This is the main FXML layout)

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox fx:controller="Transcoro.Controllers.TabManager" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="442.0" prefWidth="338.0" spacing="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="124.0">
         <children>
            <VBox prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="90.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" />
            <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="165.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="Bienvenido, Rodolfo">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label text="Administrador" />
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </HBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
         </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="15.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </HBox>
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Unidades" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2491ff" />
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Empleados" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2491ff" />
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Clientes" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2491ff" />
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Viajes" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2491ff" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

**sideMenu.fxml** (This is the sideMenu FXML layout)

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="442.0" prefWidth="338.0" spacing="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="124.0">
         <children>
            <VBox prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="90.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" />
            <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="165.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="Bienvenido, Rodolfo">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label text="Administrador" />
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </HBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
         </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="15.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </HBox>
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Unidades" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2491ff" />
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Empleados" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2491ff" />
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Clientes" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2491ff" />
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Viajes" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2491ff" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</fx:root>
```

**TabManager.java** (This is the sideMenu JavaFX controller)

```
package Transcoro.Controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TabManager extends VBox {

    public TabManager(){
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/view/sideMenu.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainLayout.java** (This is the mainLayout JavaFX Controller)

```
package Transcoro.Core;

import Transcoro.Controllers.TabManager;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainLayout extends BorderPane {
    @FXML
    private VBox sideMenu;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane innerContent;

    @FXML
    private HBox upperMenu;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane contentScroll;

    @FXML
    private VBox otherPane;

    public MainLayout(){

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/view/Custom.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

        TabManager _tabs = new TabManager();
        this.setSideMenu(_tabs);
    }
```

What I want to do is the following:

I have two layouts, the base which is the main Layout and sideMenu layout in another FXML

When I instantiate the mainLayout in my root that works fine, then when I want to  insert the TabManager (VBox) into sideMenu (VBox from FXML) it doesn't work... I'm doing this:

```
    TabManager _tabs = new TabManager();
    this.setSideMenu(_tabs);
```

The only way I have made it work is by adding:

```
this.setLeft(this.sideMenu);
```

OR

```
this.setLeft(_tabs);
```

Which I think it shouldn't work that why, because I'm already stating that sideMenu goes on the Left BorderPane side, any idea on how should I approach this?

Comment: Even if I edit the sideMenu with style insets it does work, but the Tab Manager VBox does not get into the sideMenu

Comment: Custom.fxml's controller class is `MainLayout` or `Transcoro.Controllers.TabManager`? `fxmlLoader.setController(this);` and `<VBox fx:controller="Transcoro.Controllers.TabManager" ....` are conflicting.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself which FXML is matching which controller class.

Comment: Custom.fxml -> MainLayout.java AND 
sideMenu.fxml -> TabManager.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, remove `fx:controller="Transcoro.Controllers.TabManager"` from Custom.fxml. The controller is `MainLayout`, which you will set via `FXMLLoader`.

Secondly, don't call `fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);` in `MainLayout`. You should instead retrieve the root node out from Custom.fxml, then add it to `MainLayout`, which itself is a `BorderPane`.

```
Parent root = fxmlLoader.getRoot();
this.setCenter(root);
```

This will put everything from Custom.fxml as the center child of `MainLayout`.

Thirdly, `setLeft()` is working because you are setting the `TabManager` instance (which is a `VBox`) as the left child of `MainLayout`. `setSideMenu()` (which is assumed as the setter of `@FXML private VBox sideMenu` does not work because `sideMenu` is just a reference injected into the controller. When you change this reference, it does not change the original layout.